# UIWebview Leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I want to load a gif image with webView,And it works well.But when i find leaks with instruments,there is a memory leak. Who can tell me why,Here is the code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icon_coinMoney_image" ofType:@"gif"];
UIWebView *gifWebView = ({
    UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView new];  //Leaks Here
    [self addSubview:webView];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    webView.opaque = NO;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [webView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(backImageView.mas_left).offset(-MARGIN);
        make.centerY.mas_equalTo(backImageView.mas_centerY).offset(1.f);
        make.size.mas_equalTo(CGSizeMake(ZLL_AUTOSIZING_WIDTH(30.f), ZLL_AUTOSIZING_HEIGTH(30.f)));
    }];
    [webView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [webView.layer setCornerRadius:ZLL_AUTOSIZING_WIDTH(15.f)];
    webView;
});
```

Comment: What does the retain cycle diagram in Instruments show?

Comment: _objc_msgSend_uncached ,And only 4 bits,I cannot push image here

Comment: It's probably a false positive, and even if it's not, it isn't your problem (it's Apple's problem). Anyway, 4 bits is trivial, laugh an evil laugh and move on.